# Rails and Rspec - can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am creating a Rails application with TDD using rspec. I am getting an error I can't remove :

```
Failure/Error: invalid_user = User.new(@attr.merge("provider" => ""))
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: uid, info
```

Here is my user spec :

`user_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before(:each) do
  @attr = {"provider" => "providerexample", "uid" => "uidexample", "info" => {"name" =>     "Example"}}
 end

it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
  user = User.create_with_omniauth(@attr)
end

it "should require a provider" do
  invalid_user = User.new(@attr.merge("provider" => ""))
  invalid_user.should_not be_valid
end 

it "should require a uid" do
  invalid_user = User.new(@attr.merge("uid" => ""))
  invalid_user.should_not be_valid
end
end
```

And my `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :credits, :email, :provider

  validates :name, :provider, :uid, :presence => true

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid      = auth["uid"]
    user.name     = auth["info"]["name"]
  end
 end
```

end

If I debug the `mass-assign` error by adding `uid` and `info` to the `attr_accessible`, I still get the following error `unknown attribute: info`.

Comment: What is this doing in your @attr? `"info" => {"name" =>     "Example"}`

Comment: you are right, it mustn't go there. The thing is I need to pass `auth["info"]` to `create_with_omniauth`. How can I do that?

Comment: I created an answer that should work for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge what you had as @attr with info, then it'll exist for the create_with_omniauth call, but not the regular create methods.

```
describe User do
  let(:user_attributes) { {"provider" => "providerexample", "uid" => "uidexample"} }

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    expect {
      User.create_with_omniauth(user_attributes.merge({"info" => {"name" => "example"}))
    }.to not_raise_error
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, I had managed to get something similar to your code. Should I use `expect {...` instead of letting rspec raise an error by itself like in my question's code?

Comment: Cool... I would have some form of positive assertions in the code. I think something like `user = User.create_with_omniauth; user.should be_persisted` is better still.